# how to find already values in the array element

Tags: java, arrays

I need to insert a student ID to the `id` array and find out whether or not that number already exists. So now when i run this program first it asks me to input student ID then check the whole ID array to check if any other numbers equal that ID. If the ID doesn't already exist, it is stored, after which the program asks for the student name.

Next round if I give an ID that's already stored, it gives me a message "Already Exists" and then tells me "input Student id" again and I want to give it a number that it doesn't already have. So if the ID doesn't already exist, then it should store it at the index `i` in the array. However, this does not work properly as I want.

This is what I want the input and output to look like

> Input the id for  0 : s001 
>   Enter Student name : suraj 
>  Input the id for 1 : s002 
>  Enter
>   Student name : sanuka 
>  Input the id for  2 : s002 
>  this id is
>   already exists. Input the id for  2 :

However, this is what it gives me

> Input the id for  0 : s001 
>  Enter 
>   Student name : suraj 
>  Input the id for 1 : s002
>  Enter Student
>   name : sanuka 
>  Input the id for  2 : s002
>  this id is already
>   exists.( this is what i want)
>  Input the id for  2 : s003
>  Enter
>   Student name : s002
>  Input the id for  3 : s001 (but some times
>   when i input already stored number,it doesn't work like this line)
>   this id is already exists.
>  Enter Student name :(if that already
>   exists, "Enter student name " have displayed for me.)

My code

```
class Demo2{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

            String [] id=new String[5];
            String [] name=new String[id.length];

            L1: for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++){
                //id[0]="d";
                System.out.print("Input the id for  "+i+" : ");
                String tempory=input.next();

                L2: for (int j = 0; j < id.length; j++){
                    if(tempory.equals(id[j])){

                        System.out.println("this id is already exists.");
                        i--;
                        break L2;
                    }

                }

                if(!tempory.equals(id[i])){
                    id[i]=tempory;

                    System.out.print("Enter Student name : ");
                    name[i]=input.next();

                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(id));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
        }

}
```

please solve me this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if `tempory.equals(id[j])` and if so confirming the studentId exists. Within this your then doing `i--` (too early). Use a variable and update it to true when a match is found. Something like:

```
import java.util.*;

class Demo2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] id = new String[5];
        String[] name = new String[id.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            //id[0]="d";
            System.out.print("Input the id for  " + i + " : ");
            String tempory = input.next();

            // check if ID exists?
            boolean studentIdFound = false; // try to make it true if there's a match
            for (int j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
                if (tempory.equals(id[j])) {
                    System.out.println("this id is already exists.");
                    studentIdFound = true;  // <<< removed i-- here as it was too early
                    break;
                }
            }

            // either the studentId was found, or not found so...

            if (!studentIdFound) {
                id[i] = tempory;

                System.out.print("Enter Student name : ");
                name[i] = input.next();
            } 
            if (studentIdFound) {
                i--; // retry
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(id));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
    }

}
```

Comment: first, i would like to thank you a lot for solving my question. i have doubt about this. why you use boolean variable for this?

Comment: This is purely to make it clearer for you to see the problem. You don't have to use the variable. But if the app `break`s after `i--`, the application logic breaks. This is because we cannot infer from the current value of `i` whether it was modified or not. We could just `break` without the boolean and check `!tempory.equals(id[i])`, as in your original solution, and you'll end up with the same logic as in my solution, minus the boolean... but it wouldn't be as obvious then